# Bundle errors when checking previous msi version that was written in Installshield

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.10

I am having trouble running an MSI when the previous version, which was written in Installshield, is already on the machine.  The error is failure to convert the previous version number because its not formatted correctly.  I have since created my own custom BA hoping that I could get around that problem but I haven't figured out where I need to hookup to change the MSI state from Unknown to Present so it can run the upgrade.  Everything runs fine if its a clean install or if I run the MSI directly, its only when Burn fails to convert the version.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I am getting an "Invalid package current state result encountered during plan: 0" message in the log, then "Failed to calculate plan actions for package:"

Comment: What is the version? I think I've seen this error where the 3rd or 4th part of the version is larger than unsigned short (65355) which is invalid for a "Version"